# Can the OpenShift laravel cartridge be updated using composer selfupdate?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, openshift

I'm testing an OpenShift cartridge with laravel 4.2.
When I try to  execute the command

```
    composer selfupdate
```

I get this error:

```
    [Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]                                                                                                 
    Filesystem exception:                                                                                                                     
    Composer update failed: the "/var/lib/openshift/.cartridge_repository/redhat-php/0.0.24/usr/bin/composer.phar" file could not be written
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - no the OpenShift PHP cartridge cannot be updated using `composer self-update`. Updating Composer requires root privileges.

The [Laravel 5 QuickStart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0) uses a custom version of OpenShift's PHP 5.4 cartridge. The only change with the custom PHP 5.4 cartridge is Composer has been updated. You can either switch over to Laravel 5, or simply run Laravel 4.2 using the custom PHP 5.4 cartridge.

To run Laravel 5.0 with the custom cartridge using the QuickStart:

```
rhc app create laravelapp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luciddreamz/openshift-php/master/metadata/manifest.yml mysql-5.5 --from-code=https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel
```

If you want to Run Laravel 4.2, you can create an empty PHP 5.4 app with MySQL using the custom cartridge:

```
rhc app create laravelapp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/luciddreamz/openshift-php/master/metadata/manifest.yml mysql-5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

When you run `composer self-update` this updates composer itself. If you have globally installed composer then you likely need to use `sudo` to have permission to overwrite that file.

If you're just wanting to update/install laravel then you can run `composer update` and `composer install` as appropriate.

Comment: excellent local works perfect but OpenShift cartridge has some restrictions, I will look for an updated cartridge